# Unwrapping password from auth-sources

Tags: elisp

I'm using auth-source-search to retrieve passwords from ~/.authinfo.gpg. According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/auth.html#Help-for-developers) I may have to unwrap the secret property because it's in a function.

```
(let ((secret (plist-get found :secret)))
            (if (functionp secret)
                (funcall secret)
              secret))
```

But in my case the password is somehow wrapped in two functions, so I would have to retrieve it with:

```
(funcall (funcall secret))
```

This would result in very ugly code.

```
(let ((secret (plist-get info :secret))
    (if (functionp secret)
        (if (functionp (funcall secret))
            (funcall (funcall secret))
        (funcall secret))
    secret)))
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?